# Change automatically CSS via JS at a certain breakpoint

Tags: javascript, css, hidden, responsive, display

I am building a responsive navigation therefore I have a button that changes the styling of the div **#navigation** via **Javascript**. (toggle between `display: none;` and `display: block;` .
On small screens it works perfectly. However, when I show and hide the navigation on the a small screen and resize the window after it the navigation is still hidden.

Is there a way to change the css automatically if the window has a certain size?

Here is the code I'm using (by the way: I'm new to Javascript)
Again: See what happens when you make the window smaller, open and close the navigation and resize the window again. The navigation is (not as wanted) still hidden:
http://codepen.io/HannesDev/pen/grjdqK

---

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-Nav">Navigation</div>
<nav id="nav-hor" role="navigation">
<ul>
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
 </ul>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

CSS:

```
html{
  background: lime;
}
/* The Button */
.btn-Nav{
  border: 2px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;

}
/* The button changes to the greyed out closed area on the right */
.btn-Nav_open{
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 80vw;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: .2;
  padding: .2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}

/* The Navigation on small screens */
#nav-hor{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 999;
  border-right: 1px solid grey
}


@media (min-width: 50em) { 
  html{
    background: red;
  }
  /* Don't show the button on bigger screens */
  .btn-Nav{
    display: none;
  }

 /* The Navigation for bigger screens */
  #nav-hor {
    /* Clean up */
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.querySelector('.btn-Nav').onclick = function(){
    // closed
      if(this.className.match('btn-Nav btn-Nav_open')) {
          this.className = 'btn-Nav';
          document.getElementsByClassName("btn-Nav")[0].innerHTML = "Navigation";
          document.getElementById('nav-hor').style.display = "none";
          document.body.style.overflow = "auto";

      }
      // open
      else {
          this.className = 'btn-Nav btn-Nav_open';

          document.getElementsByClassName("btn-Nav")[0].innerHTML = "&#215;";
          document.getElementById('nav-hor').style.display = "block";
          document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
      }
  };
};
```

Comment: Please add your relevant "*[mcve]*" code in your question, don't just link to t, show it to us. This is to guard against the code being lost in the future, due to deletion, reorganisation, business failure... all of which would render your question non-useful for future visitors.

Comment: You could use `window.matchMedia` and the `resize` event.

Comment: Thank you @gcampbell ! That made it work :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the css automatically if the window has a certain size?

Absolutely, however, you don't need Javascript to do it. CSS offers something called media queries, which allows you to change the styles of elements based on certain conditions. For your specific case, something along the lines of

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #navigation {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This will change the display of the #navigation element to block only when the browser window is smaller than 500px. The max-width value can most definitely be changed. There are some other awesome things you can do with media queries, and examples of them can be found at: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used media queries already and it works fine. However, on in this case this does not work because I overwrite the css style with javascript. This overwrite is globally and therefore even when the media queries says `display: block` the JS made the element to `display:none`.